# porting users from firebase to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, firebase, mongoose, firebase-authentication

I'm currently trying to export a project that used firebase auth to mongodb. While I'm able to query and backfill the user info into my new mongodb database, I can't seem to figure out how to access and backfill passwords in firebase. Any ideas?

Comment: To my understand, there is no way to get the password from firebase.

Comment: Firebase is more of a "service" than a database in that the "database" part is basically "hidden". So direct access to things like passwords would seem to be not something typically allowed. There does appear to be an ["export feature" though](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth) so that's likely going to be the place to look. Of course you are going to need to re-implement the same password crypto routines or arrange for passwords to be reset and replaced anyway with any migration. No way will you ever get passwords "in the clear".

Comment: Reach out to Firebase Support. Also the scrypt hashing algo that Firebase Auth uses is modified. They will provide the instructions you need.